# What is the best way to store big vector to database with python?

Tags: python, sql, database

I want to classify some text. So I have to compare it with other texts. After representing texts as vectors how can I store them (very big lists of float values) to SQL database for using them later?

My idea is using pickle module:

```
vector=text_to_vector(text)
present=pickle.dumps(big_list)
some_db.save(text_id,present)

#later
present=some_db.get(text_id)
vector=pickle.loads(present)
```

Is it fast and effective if I have thousends of texts?

Comment: Well, it depends. Are you ever going to need to query a particular element individually? It's generally a bad idea to store serialized values in a database.

Comment: Yes. What else, if not database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that `pickle` and databases don't work too well together.

Python's [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) is for serializing Python objects to a format, that can then be read back in to Python objects by Python.  Although it's very easy to serialize with `pickle`, you can't* query this serialized format, you can't* read it into a program in another language.  Check out [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle), another Python module, for faster `pickle`-ing.

Databases, on the other hand, are great for persisting data *in such a way that it is queryable and non-language-specific*.  But the cost is that it's generally harder to get/put data into/from the database.  That's why there's special tools like [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), and endless blog-based debates about the benefits/horrors of Object-Relation-Mapping software.

`Pickle`-ing objects, and then sending them to a database such as MySQL or SQL Server is probably not a good idea.  However, check out [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve), another Python module for database-like persistence of Python objects.

So, to sum up:

- use `pickle` or `shelve` if you just need to save the data for later use by a Python program
- map objects to a database if you want to persist the data for general use, with the understanding that this requires more effort
- performance-wise, `cPickle` will probably win over a database + object/relation mapping

---

*: at least, not without a lot of effort and/or special libraries.